# Proof of the Kramers-Kronig relations: How does the contribution from the larger semicircle vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics

Wikipedia gives a derivation of the [Kramers-Kronig relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations#Derivation) where they consider an integral of the form $\oint\frac{\chi(\omega^\prime)}{\omega^\prime-\omega}d\omega^\prime$ with $\chi(\omega^\prime)$ assumed to be analytic in the complex upper half plane. Then they argue that

> The length of the semicircular segment increases proportionally to $|\omega^\prime|$, but the integral over it vanishes in the limit because $\chi(\omega^\prime)$ vanishes at least as fast as $1/|\omega^\prime|$.

How do they arrive at the conclusion that $\chi(\omega^\prime)$ vanishes at least as fast as $1/|\omega^\prime|$?

Comment: That is an assumption. You cannot derive it from anywhere.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wikipedia does not mention that it is an assumption. Even if it is an assumption why make such an ad hoc assumption?

Comment: The Derivation section has some misleading phrasing, but you can see it stated explicitly as an assumption in the formulation section of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Aha! I missed that. Thanks.